# Where do the properties of System.getProperties come from?

Tags: java, properties

When I call the method `System.getProperties();` and I print them it gives
a big list with key-value pairs without setting properties. Where does `Java` get
those properties from?

Comment: Java initializes its own `Properties` object from a combination of properties of the underlying computer and hard-coded values inside the VM's implementation. [This newsgroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.help/-JBBUicGRH4) covers the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Operating System (environment) hosting Java. Check [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

> In Properties, we examined the way an application can use Properties objects to maintain its configuration. The Java platform itself uses a Properties object to maintain its own configuration. **The System class maintains a Properties object that describes the configuration of the current working environment**. System properties include information about the current user, the current version of the Java runtime, and the character used to separate components of a file path name.

---

```
Key                 Meaning
-----------------   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
"file.separator"    Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.
"java.class.path"   Path used to find directories and JAR archives containing class files. Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific character specified in the path.separator property.
"java.home"         Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
"java.vendor"       JRE vendor name
"java.vendor.url"   JRE vendor URL
"java.version"      JRE version number
"line.separator"    Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files
"os.arch"           Operating system architecture
"os.name"           Operating system name
"os.version"        Operating system version
"path.separator"    Path separator character used in java.class.path
"user.dir"          User working directory
"user.home"         User home directory
"user.name"         User account name
```